# console.log() in windows 8 javascript/visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

When I use console.log("Some text output") in javascript in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8 metro programming where is the text being sent to? Where can I view it? I've got the "Output" panel up but I do not see the log text.

Am I not using the right function? Is there another function I must use to print to Output?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To actually see the JavaScript console select `DEBUG > Windows > JavaScript Console` in the Visual Studio menus. Then you can use the good old [`console.log()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696634.aspx) to write to it, but you can also use the related `WinJS` functions:

There is [`WinJS.log()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150612.aspx) to log something after creating the function with [`WinJS.Utilities.startLog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701617.aspx):

```
WinJS.Utilities.startLog({type: "info", tags: "custom" });
WinJS.log("my message", "info", "custom");
```

---

Here's some additional information on the `WinJS` logging functions:

> `startLog(options)`: Configures a logger that writes messages containing the specified tags to the JavaScript console.

The `options` object **must** contain a `type` which is supposed to be one of `error`, `warn`, `info` or `perf`. Unless you want to capture all log entries, also add `tags` to the object containing a space-separated list of tags you want to be logged.

`WinJS.log(message, tags, type)`: This function **does not exist** by default. However, it is created by your `startLog()` call. You could also create it manually but since you want logging to the console using `startLog()` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, but where does the output actually go to? I've changed my code but still can't see the output

Comment: DEBUG > Windows > JavaScript Console

Comment: Thanks. Actually console.log() stuff also shows up in the JavaScript Console!

Comment: I do see the benefit of WinJS.log(). In a much bigger app with a lot more debug outputs it would be very handy to be able to classify output types

Answer (score 1):

If you need to debug the application in a live environment, you can use a simple on-screen console.log replacement, which you can activate using the ~ key.

Source code here:
https://gist.github.com/4012355

Answer (score 0):

I might be replying to an old post, or maybe you have discovered your way to serve your purpose, but I tried console.log() and WinJS.log() and the javascript console seem to return 'undefined' for both. Also, I made sure with 'debugger;' statement that that code was is executing. Now I am assuming here that you need logging for debugging purposes then what I would prefer to "print" to my screen now is:

```
<body>
  <label id="lblMessage">test</label>
</body>
```

and then in JS :

```
function f(message) {
  document.getElementById('lblMessage').innerText = message;
}
```

( and then, place a call to this function where needed - in my case it was, app.onactivated function)

Comment: This is a very bad, ugly indeed, option... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the log through the EventViewer. Here are the steps to enable this:

Open Event Viewer
Navigate to Application and Services Log
Expand Microsoft/Windows/AppHost
Left click to select Admin
Right click Admin and then select View => Show Analytic and Debug Logs